# JBoss hangs on start

Tags: java, jboss

I'm trying to deploy a WAR file on my JBOSS Server.

I have the following setup:

In C:\jboss\jboss-as-7.1.1.Final\standalone\deployments I have two files:

1. MY_APP.dodeploy
2. MY_APP.war

I then run the following

```
C:\jboss\jboss-as-7.1.1.Final\bin>standalone.bat
Calling "C:\jboss\jboss-as-7.1.1.Final\bin\standalone.conf.bat"
===============================================================================

  JBoss Bootstrap Environment

  JBOSS_HOME: C:\jboss\jboss-as-7.1.1.Final

  JAVA: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_05\bin\java

  JAVA_OPTS: -XX:+TieredCompilation -Dprogram.name=standalone.bat -Xms256M -Xmx2
048M -XX:MaxPermSize=512M -Dsun.rmi.dgc.client.gcInterval=3600000 -Dsun.rmi.dgc.
server.gcInterval=3600000 -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Dorg.jboss.resolver.w
arning=true -Djboss.modules.system.pkgs=org.jboss.byteman -Djboss.server.default
.config=standalone.xml

===============================================================================

Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=512M; sup
port was removed in 8.0
10:08:55,437 INFO  [org.jboss.modules] JBoss Modules version 1.1.1.GA
10:08:55,853 INFO  [org.jboss.msc] JBoss MSC version 1.0.2.GA
10:08:55,894 INFO  [org.jboss.as] JBAS015899: JBoss AS 7.1.1.Final "Brontes" sta
rting
```

But it just hangs. It doesn't go any further.

Ideas?

Comment: Look in the log to see if there is additional information.  No perm gen in JDK 8 anymore, but that shouldn't stop things.

Comment: in standalone.xml you should be able to set the FILE loglevel to TRACE and get far more information about what Jboss is doing under the hood.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

JBoss AS 7.x [does not support Java 8](https://community.jboss.org/message/808212).

Use Java 7 or upgrade to WildFly 8.

Comment: I had the same problem with Jboss AS 7.1.1 hanging up on the startup. I used wildfly 8. Worked like a charm.