# jBoss stuck at starting in netbeans and never starts

Tags: java, jboss7.x, netbeans-8

I am running Java 8, NetBeans 8 and jBoss 7.1.1-Final.

When I right click on the jboss application server and select "start", it starts going and then never fully starts up. Here is my output.

Calling "C:\Athabasca\Comp 489\TME3\jBoss\jboss-as-7.1.1.Final\bin\standalone.conf.bat"

## "JAVA_OPTS already set in environment; overriding default settings with values: -Xms128m -Xmx512m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m"

JBoss Bootstrap Environment

JBOSS_HOME: C:\Athabasca\Comp 489\TME3\jBoss\jboss-as-7.1.1.Final

JAVA: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_05\bin\java

JAVA_OPTS: -XX:+TieredCompilation -Dprogram.name=standalone.bat -Xms128m -Xmx512m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m

===============================================================================

09:30:53,949 INFO  [org.jboss.modules] JBoss Modules version 1.1.1.GA
09:30:54,056 INFO  [org.jboss.msc] JBoss MSC version 1.0.2.GA
09:30:54,082 INFO  [org.jboss.as] JBAS015899: JBoss AS 7.1.1.Final "Brontes" starting

And that is where it sits forever. At one point, it did go through a lot more stuff and then got stuck at Bound data source [java:jboss/datasources/ExampleDS] but I havnt been able to get it to do that again.

I have tried with jboss 7.1.1 and jboss 7.1.0.
I am logged into the computer using the Administrator account. All other java programs work fine. I have set the JBOSS Home enviro variable in the system as well.

Below is a copy of the boot.log although it doesnt seem to show anything useful as far as I can tell.

```
10:56:44,294 INFO  [org.jboss.modules] JBoss Modules version 1.1.1.GA
10:56:44,414 INFO  [org.jboss.msc] JBoss MSC version 1.0.2.GA
10:56:44,441 INFO  [org.jboss.as] JBAS015899: JBoss AS 7.1.1.Final "Brontes" starting
10:56:44,442 DEBUG [org.jboss.as.config] Configured system properties:
    awt.toolkit = sun.awt.windows.WToolkit
    file.encoding = Cp1252
    file.encoding.pkg = sun.io
    file.separator = \
    java.awt.graphicsenv = sun.awt.Win32GraphicsEnvironment
    java.awt.printerjob = sun.awt.windows.WPrinterJob
    java.class.path = C:\Athabasca\Comp 489\TME3\jBoss\jboss-as-7.1.1.Final\jboss-modules.jar
    java.class.version = 52.0
    java.endorsed.dirs = C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_05\jre\lib\endorsed
    java.ext.dirs = C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_05\jre\lib\ext;C:\Windows\Sun\Java\lib\ext
    java.home = C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_05\jre
    java.io.tmpdir = C:\Users\ADMINI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\
    java.library.path = C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_05\bin;C:\Windows\Sun\Java\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Program Files\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\OpenCL SDK\3.0\bin\x86;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\OpenCL SDK\3.0\bin\x64;C:\Program Files (x86)\ATI Technologies\ATI.ACE\Core-Static;C:\xampp\mysql\bin;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_05\bin\;.
    java.runtime.name = Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment
    java.runtime.version = 1.8.0_05-b13
    java.specification.name = Java Platform API Specification
    java.specification.vendor = Oracle Corporation
    java.specification.version = 1.8
    java.util.logging.manager = org.jboss.logmanager.LogManager
    java.vendor = Oracle Corporation
    java.vendor.url = http://java.oracle.com/
    java.vendor.url.bug = http://bugreport.sun.com/bugreport/
    java.version = 1.8.0_05
    java.vm.info = mixed mode
    java.vm.name = Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM
    java.vm.specification.name = Java Virtual Machine Specification
    java.vm.specification.vendor = Oracle Corporation
    java.vm.specification.version = 1.8
    java.vm.vendor = Oracle Corporation
    java.vm.version = 25.5-b02
    javax.management.builder.initial = org.jboss.as.jmx.PluggableMBeanServerBuilder
    javax.xml.datatype.DatatypeFactory = __redirected.__DatatypeFactory
    javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory = __redirected.__DocumentBuilderFactory
    javax.xml.parsers.SAXParserFactory = __redirected.__SAXParserFactory
    javax.xml.stream.XMLEventFactory = __redirected.__XMLEventFactory
    javax.xml.stream.XMLInputFactory = __redirected.__XMLInputFactory
    javax.xml.stream.XMLOutputFactory = __redirected.__XMLOutputFactory
    javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory = __redirected.__TransformerFactory
    javax.xml.validation.SchemaFactory:http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema = __redirected.__SchemaFactory
    javax.xml.xpath.XPathFactory:http://java.sun.com/jaxp/xpath/dom = __redirected.__XPathFactory
    jboss.home.dir = C:\Athabasca\Comp 489\TME3\jBoss\jboss-as-7.1.1.Final
    jboss.host.name = master
    jboss.modules.dir = C:\Athabasca\Comp 489\TME3\jBoss\jboss-as-7.1.1.Final\modules
    jboss.node.name = master
    jboss.qualified.host.name = master
    jboss.server.base.dir = C:\Athabasca\Comp 489\TME3\jBoss\jboss-as-7.1.1.Final\standalone
    jboss.server.config.dir = C:\Athabasca\Comp 489\TME3\jBoss\jboss-as-7.1.1.Final\standalone\configuration
    jboss.server.data.dir = C:\Athabasca\Comp 489\TME3\jBoss\jboss-as-7.1.1.Final\standalone\data
    jboss.server.deploy.dir = C:\Athabasca\Comp 489\TME3\jBoss\jboss-as-7.1.1.Final\standalone\data\content
    jboss.server.log.dir = C:\Athabasca\Comp 489\TME3\jBoss\jboss-as-7.1.1.Final\standalone\log
    jboss.server.name = master
    jboss.server.temp.dir = C:\Athabasca\Comp 489\TME3\jBoss\jboss-as-7.1.1.Final\standalone\tmp
    line.separator = 

    logging.configuration = file:C:\Athabasca\Comp 489\TME3\jBoss\jboss-as-7.1.1.Final\standalone/configuration/logging.properties
    module.path = C:\Athabasca\Comp 489\TME3\jBoss\jboss-as-7.1.1.Final\modules
    org.jboss.boot.log.file = C:\Athabasca\Comp 489\TME3\jBoss\jboss-as-7.1.1.Final\standalone\log\boot.log
    org.xml.sax.driver = __redirected.__XMLReaderFactory
    os.arch = amd64
    os.name = Windows 7
    os.version = 6.1
    path.separator = ;
    program.name = standalone.bat
    sun.arch.data.model = 64
    sun.boot.class.path = C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_05\jre\lib\resources.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_05\jre\lib\rt.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_05\jre\lib\sunrsasign.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_05\jre\lib\jsse.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_05\jre\lib\jce.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_05\jre\lib\charsets.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_05\jre\lib\jfr.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_05\jre\classes
    sun.boot.library.path = C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_05\jre\bin
    sun.cpu.endian = little
    sun.cpu.isalist = amd64
    sun.desktop = windows
    sun.io.unicode.encoding = UnicodeLittle
    sun.java.command = C:\Athabasca\Comp 489\TME3\jBoss\jboss-as-7.1.1.Final\jboss-modules.jar -mp C:\Athabasca\Comp 489\TME3\jBoss\jboss-as-7.1.1.Final\modules -jaxpmodule javax.xml.jaxp-provider org.jboss.as.standalone -Djboss.home.dir=C:\Athabasca\Comp 489\TME3\jBoss\jboss-as-7.1.1.Final
    sun.java.launcher = SUN_STANDARD
    sun.jnu.encoding = Cp1252
    sun.management.compiler = HotSpot 64-Bit Tiered Compilers
    sun.os.patch.level = Service Pack 1
    user.country = US
    user.dir = C:\Athabasca\Comp 489\TME3\jBoss\jboss-as-7.1.1.Final\bin
    user.home = C:\Users\Administrator
    user.language = en
    user.name = Administrator
    user.script = 
    user.timezone = America/Denver
    user.variant = 
10:56:44,448 DEBUG [org.jboss.as.config] VM Arguments: -XX:+TieredCompilation -Dprogram.name=standalone.bat -Xms128m -Xmx512m -Dorg.jboss.boot.log.file=C:\Athabasca\Comp 489\TME3\jBoss\jboss-as-7.1.1.Final\standalone\log\boot.log -Dlogging.configuration=file:C:\Athabasca\Comp 489\TME3\jBoss\jboss-as-7.1.1.Final\standalone/configuration/logging.properties
```

Comment: so its a coincidence that this question is nearly identical to this other one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24678848/jboss-hangs-on-start ?

Comment: Looks like pretty much the exact same problem except that in one instance I was able to get it to go a bit father and hang on something different...however that was when I tried 7.1.0.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This was posted as the answer to the duplicate question that Gimby mentioned and was the solution for this. And yes, it was a total coincidence that we both ran into this problem at nearly the same time.

JBoss AS 7.x does not support Java 8.

I installed jdk 7.x and set that as the java version for my project and it worked fine after that.